# How to negate exit code status to be used in Kubernetes livenessProbe?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, grep, centos, livenessprobe

How to negate exit code status to be used in `Kubernetes` `livenessProbe`?

I'll be using the `grep` command and I would like to do below as a check.

- Return exit value 0, if `grep` has no hit
- Return exit value 1, if `grep` has a hit

Since normally, grep will return 0 if there is a hit, can I negate this something like shown below?

```
!$(cat filet.txt | grep keyword)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can give it try

example :

```
    livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - cat filet.txt | grep keyword
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
```

you should checkout if helpful

```
-v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

You can also try `-c`

```
echo 'Test' | grep -c T
```

**1**

```
echo 'Test' | grep -c N
```

**0**

**shell script**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(echo 'Test' | grep -c T) ]; then
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

the easiest way would be writing shell script and managing the exit code for liveness as you want 0 or 1 and based on that liveness will restart the pod.

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - /home/test/health.sh
```

Comment: in your example, the pod will retart if there are no hits ?

Comment: i think, but easiest way would be using the shell script option last one I have shared, that will be good to manage the exit status code and manage code as per need.

Comment: I will give the shell script approach a try. I think it is the better solution. Can you upvote my question bro? I can't upvote your answer for now since I still have less rep :(

Comment: it worked man. Really helped a lot.

Comment: glad to hear that...!

Comment: There a little issue with the answer. All cases will lead to exit 1 path.

Comment: It's just an info bro, no need to edit. I just added a conditional operator to make it work.

Comment: got it, thanks for update. however you can share please might be helpful to others.